# Imprecise answer accepted, what to do?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer

On [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304145/one-particular-button-on-the-keyboard-does-not-work-if-two-other-keys-are-being?rq=1), the accepted answer mentions key ghosting, although the actual issue the user is experiencing is key *rollover*.
This answer is not outright *wrong* and it has the potential of offering help to OP but it may just as easily mislead OP or anyone else looking to this question of guidance into buying a keyboard boasting "anti-ghosting" tech.
The result of an anti ghosting keyboard that does not have a higher key rollover would be that the key would be ignored just as in OP's experience.
What OP needs is a NKRO keyboard or either way a keyboard that is able to face the issue of key rollover AND ghosting.

[Key Rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29) as opposed to [Key ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Ghosting).

Now to the question: Does this imprecision warrant an edit? Or a lengthy explanation in a new answer? Does it warrant a comment? or should this be left alone?

I did post a comment, not noticing this post was quite old already, mentioning this imprecision.

I believe this is different from general cases I've seen on the suggested answers like: [What do we do with highly upvoted, accepted, wrong answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/what-do-we-do-with-highly-upvoted-accepted-wrong-answers) as this is not *technically* a wrong answer but it has the potential to be misleading in it's imprecision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the actions you have taken so far have been appropriate under these specific circumstances. Note that the user is still active(ish): last seen 18 hours ago and is a high rep user on another stack so it is likely they will see your comment. My advice would be to wait a day or two to see if the user either replies (who knows you *may* be wrong and their answer is the more accurate one) or edits their answer to update per your comment.

After a period of time has passed and nothing happens it would be best to suggest an edit to the answer with the changes. However, I would take care not to completely re-write the answer or make substantial changes.

If this gets rejected or you do feel like you have a lot to write about it which would warrant an answer in its own right, post your own answer!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the answer is overall correct, as i mention it is just the terminology that has been used that might be misleading and is generally improper to address this issue as ghosting, this being said, the keyboard advertising seems to use this very terminology improperly at times. In general almost all keyboards, even the cheap office ones will have anti ghosting functions as this would be a critical failure of the hardware but most non-gaming related hardware does not account for rollover because of the construction cost constraints.